# At what volume of data does a JSON data structure become too slow?

Tags: javascript, json, performance, simile

I'm using MIT's Simile to display thumbnails and links with faceted filtering.  I works great, but large data sets (greater than 500 elements) start to slow significantly.  My user base will tolerate seconds, but not 10's of seconds, and certainly not minutes while the page renders.

Is it the volume of data in the JSON structure?

Is it Simile's method of parsing?

Comment: Why not profile your application stack - then you'll know for sure where the bottleneck is instead of conjuncture!

Comment: measurement is better than *conjecture*

Comment: I did.  A dozen elements and I get sub-second response.  A hundred goes to a second or two.  A thousand starts to take anywhere from 6 to 20 seconds depending on the number of facets.

Comment: Thinking about it, this is a pretty gross measurement on my part... What would you suggest to profile Simile's JavaScript stack?

Comment: @dacracot - where you able to solve this?  i am running into the same issue ..

Comment: @oo - No.  We switched to solr.

Answer (score 1):

Too slow compared to what? Its probably faster than XML and easier to implement compared to your own custom binary format.

Comment: Compared to say Solr where thousands of facets get sub-second response times.

Answer (score 0):

Exhibit version 3 (http://simile-widgets.org/exhibit ) provides good interaction with up to 100,000 items.  Displaying them all can take some time if the individual items' lens template is complicated, but if you use pagination then loading, filtering, and display are all pretty quick.